# How to replace the position of a directory containing spaces

Tags: bash

I made two pipelines; this, `x="$(ls -1p | grep "/$" | tr -d "/")"` get all the sub directories from the working directory, and this, `y="$(ls -1p | grep "/$"| grep \ | tr -d "/")"` gets the sub directories that contain spaces in the working directory.

**So now what I've trying to do is to replace the position of the directory that contains spaces and puts it at the very top**, ie., say below are my sub dirs:

```
Dir1
Dir2
Dir 3
```

Now `Dir 3` goes to the top:

```
Dir 3
Dir1
Dir1
```

```
for I in $x; do
    for X in $y; do
        if [[ $I == $X ]];then
            sed "/"$X"/d" "$I"
        fi
    done
    echo "$I"
done
```

Above is my loop to do that task. It prints all the sub dirs that contains no spaces but prints it as:

```
Dir1
Dir2
sed: Dir: No such file or directory
Dir
sed: 3: No such file or directory
3
```

If anyone can help out that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `remove the name`? Do you want to `rmdir` out of
the filesystem? Besides, what do you mean by `put it at the very top`?
Do you mention about the order of printing?

Comment: That file shouldn't be deleted rather simply is placed at the top of the column along with all the other sub dirs, that do not contain spaces. Please have a look at the sample output.

Comment: Then you should not use the term `delete` or `remove`. Better to edit your title and text to clarify what you want to do from technical point of view.

Comment: Done! THANKS for the suggestion

Comment: What is your main goal, once you've listed directories with spaces? If you want to move them, use `find`. If you just want to list them, use `find`. `find . -mindepth 1 -type d -name '*[[:space:]]*'`.

Comment: @dan. I'm not familiar with `find` so is there a way using for loop to move them?

Comment: @AlyssaKowther yes, do you want to move them to a completely different directory? Or to somewhere else in the current directory?

Comment: @dan, none actually. See I need to print all the sub directories in the current working directory, so It'll print all of them. Now I need to see if any of the directories names contain spaces if they do I put them at the top of the column. So all the directories that have spaces are at top and directories with no spaces in their name are the bottom. Please check the sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer `for` loop to the `find` command, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1st loop to print the dirnames containing space character
for d in */; do                         # loops over subdirectories under current directory
    if [[ $d =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then    # if the dirname contains a space character
        echo "${d%/}"                   # then print the name removing the trailing slash
    fi
done

# 2nd loop to print the dirnames without space character
for d in */; do
    if [[ ! $d =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then  # if the dirname does not contain a space character
        echo "${d%/}"
    fi
done
```

Output with the provided example:

```
Dir 3
Dir1
Dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU find:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -name '*[[:space:]]*'       # spaces
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[^/[:space:]]+$' # no spaces
```

This is recursive.